# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable when creating a matrix with specific values

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm getting the TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable error for the following code:

```
M = 10
N = 2
vol = np.random.standard_normal((M+1,2))
rho = np.random.standard_normal((M+1,1))
gamma = np.array([0.1,0.2])
cho_matrix = np.zeros((M+1, N, N), dtype=np.float)
for t in range(1, M + 1):
    for i in range(0, N):
        for j in range(0, N):
            if j == i:
                cho_matrix[t,i,j] = vol[t,i]
            else:
                cho_matrix[t,i,j]= vol[t,i] * vol[t,j] * ((1 - gamma[i]**2)(1-gamma[j]**2))**(-1/2) * rho[t]

print(cho_matrix)
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-ed6ff4869285> in <module>()
     11                 cho_matrix[t,i,j] = vol[t,i]
     12             else:
---> 13                 cho_matrix[t,i,j]= vol[t,i] * vol[t,j] * ((1 - gamma[i]**2)(1-gamma[j]**2))**(-1/2) * rho[t]
     14 
     15 print(cho_matrix)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

In this code, I first tried with `N = 2` but I will need to extend to bigger value of `N`. Can anyone help me to get over the problem of the code?

Answer (score 1):

This bit is the problem:

```
(1 - gamma[i]**2)(1-gamma[j]**2)
```

You probably wanted a multiplication sign in between those two expressions.

In regular math notation we can write `(a)(b)` and understand that it means to multiply a and b, but in Python you have to write `(a) * (b)`.